# SugarCRM API - Filter POST - Related Module Fields

Tags: sugarcrm

I'm trying to retrieve, using REST API, a list of records and one of its related module fields. Let's assume Accounts and Opportunities.

So, [API Documentation (in the GET Filter)](http://support.sugarcrm.com/Documentation/Sugar_Developer/Sugar_Developer_Guide_7.7/Integration/Web_Services/v10/Endpoints/modulefilter_GET/) talks about defining related module in the fields parameter:

[image: Sugar CRM GET Filter fields description]

According to the same documentation, it would provide a result similiar to:

[image]

That's exactly what I need, but I'm trying to achieve this using the POST method. So, following the same path, I'm sending (using Postman):

[image]

PS: I tried all combinations of double quotes. Escaped, not escaped, with or without it, all of them give me the same result, that is:

[image]

The message is in pt-BR but it means "One of your request parameters is wrong". The HTTP status code is 422 - Unprocessable Entity.

What am I doing wrong? I tried everything and just don't know how to make it work. Looks like the documentation talks about something that simply don't work or doesn't exist.

Comment: Do you mean http://support.sugarcrm.com/Documentation/Sugar_Developer/Sugar_Developer_Guide_7.7/Integration/Web_Services/v10/Endpoints/modulefilter_POST/ ?

Comment: Yeap @Reisclef. As I said, I'm trying to do the same from the GET documentation via POST (as I believe they act the same, that's just a matter of docs completeness). BTW, I tried using GET, too, but it doesn't work either.

Comment: It's a bit strange honestly. The POST method doesn't seem to return related items. You certainly can filter on related items, but I don't see a way using POST to get them. Similarly, I don't understand why Sugar recommends sending JSON for GET requests as generally GET requests have no body.

Comment: @Reisclef using GET you can specify the list of fields you wanna get in the URL. It works fine for non-related fields, as does POST.

Comment: Agreed. So based on your comment, what exactly is the problem you're trying to solve? I'm not entirely sure what the question is now.

Comment: @Reisclef I still want to get related fields (at least using the GET method, where the docs clearly state it's possible).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, so after some research, it seems that Postman uses something similar to Chrome and it isn't really possible to send GET requests with the values in the body. However, you can...

Encode the values into the URL and send it through Postman:

```
https://yoursite.com/rest/v10/Accounts?filter%5B0%5D%5Bopportunities.date_modified%5D%5B%24gte%5D%3D2016-02-29T00%3A00%3A00&fields=cpf_c,opportunities&max_num=10
```

Use curl:

```
curl -X GET -H Host:yoursite.com -H OAuth-Token:d49c8fd4-0ae0-d9fb-7ab8-5846e5a3fa86 -H Cache-Control:no-cache -d '{"filter":[{"opportunities.date_modified":{"$gte":"2016-02-29T00:00:00"}}],"fields":["cpf_c","opportunities"],"max_num":"10"}' https://yoursite.com/rest/v10/Accounts
```

Or build the HTTP request directly, and include the body:

```
GET https://yoursite.com/rest/v10/Accounts HTTP/1.1
Host: yoursite.com
OAuth-Token:d49c8fd4-0ae0-d9fb-7ab8-5846e5a3fa86
Cache-Control:no-cache

{"filter":[{"opportunities.date_modified":{"$gte":"2016-02-29T00:00:00"}}],"fields":["cpf_c","opportunities"],"max_num":"10"}
```

To test this, I created 3 Accounts, 2 of which had an Opportunity linked. The response was this when I used "name" instead of your "cpf_c" field:

```
{
    "next_offset": -1,
    "records": [{
        "id": "64417139-459c-852f-3a73-5846ed1245c2",
        "name": "another account with opp",
        "date_modified": "2016-12-06T16:54:29+00:00",
        "opportunities": {
            "next_offset": -1,
            "records": [{
                "id": "32d1d320-c560-92d6-7def-5846eda786da",
                "date_modified": "2016-12-06T16:55:06+00:00",
                "_acl": {
                    "fields": {}
                },
                "_module": "Opportunities"
            }]
        },
        "_acl": {
            "fields": {}
        },
        "_module": "Accounts"
    }, {
        "id": "48dc47dd-bbf1-816d-b0ac-5846e6dd9e21",
        "name": "test with opp",
        "date_modified": "2016-12-06T16:23:33+00:00",
        "opportunities": {
            "next_offset": -1,
            "records": [{
                "id": "79c3bf6f-6c2b-7945-09f7-5846e6c610d7",
                "date_modified": "2016-12-06T16:24:20+00:00",
                "_acl": {
                    "fields": {}
                },
                "_module": "Opportunities"
            }]
        },
        "_acl": {
            "fields": {}
        },
        "_module": "Accounts"
    }]
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It worked (using Filter POST)!! Why did you decide to use just "opportunities" instead of the way suggested by the documentation? Would like to know how to query specific fields of the opportunity, but to be honest right now just the ID is find for me.

Comment: I didn't quite manage yet to figure out how to add the opportunity fields specifically when using GET. However, as your attempt seemed to only need the ID, I figured that would solve the problem at hand. Sure there's a way to do it, and I'll probably figure it out eventually if it bugs me enough. ;) Thanks for the upvote & answer marking, glad it helped!

Comment: I also posted this question on SugarCRM Community Forum. If I get any answer there, will update here. That's a matter of honor now.. :) Tks again!